# Как проверить базу данных?

Tags: база-данных, проверка

Получив задание на лабу, я спроектировал базу данных, и вроде все неплохо, но мне совершенно не нравиться, как сделана работа с адресами, а что-то другое в голову не приходит.

Что можно сделать для хранения адреса и есть ли в базе косяки, которые я не заметил?

Вот задание на лабу и ниже сама база. Жирным обозначены ключи.

Банковский справочник (информация для клиентов).

Банки, отделения, адреса и время работы.
Процентные ставки по кредитам и депозитам.
Виды и условия кредитования.
Сеть банкоматов.

А.
Найти банк, в котором процентные ставки по депозитам наибольшие, а по кредитам – наименьшие.

Б.
Для указанного банка найти другие банки, которые предлагают лучшие условия
кредитования.

В.
Найти банки с лучшими условиями по депозитам на один год и наибольшей сетью
банкоматов.

Г.
Найти улицу, на которой больше всего отделений банков; банкоматов.

Д.
Для указанного банка и суммы кредита показать для каждого кредитного предложения ежемесячный платеж.

Е.
Какие банки только кредитуют и не предлагают размещать депозиты?
[image]

Comment: Если вам так хочется держать в базе все города, улицы и дома в виде отдельных сущностей:

    адрес:
      city: 1-to-m cities.id
      street: 1-to-m streets.id
      building: 1-to-m buildings.id

Comment: Я тоже думал об этом варианте, но не смог понять, как сделать задание под пунктом г.

Comment: просуммируйте банкоматы/банки для каждой улицы. Отсортируйте числа по возростанию и выведите

Comment: Номера домов перенести в адрес. Пользы от отдельной сущности мало.

Comment: Если задание описано полностью, то у вас лишние сущности сплошь и рядом:

* Города. зачем они нужны? И даже если они нужны, то города должны быть в улицах, а не в адресах. Вы же не предлагаете суммировать отделения в разных городах на одинаково называющихся улицах (запрос Г)?
* Расписание. Для какого запроса оно вам нужно? Ни для какого. Это справочная информация, выводить и хранить ее можно как угодно, в частности в тексте.
* Месячный платеж. Это поле вычисляемое, и хранить его нельзя.
* Отделения и банкоматы в принципе можно было бы объединить, набор реквизитов у них одинаковый.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибок (или сомнительных мест) на самом деле очень много:

1. Вбейте гвоздь в голову тому, кто научил вас повсеместно использовать составные первичные ключи. Не то чтобы совсем ужасная практика, но все же нездоровая.
2. В таблице расписаний, по всей видимости, нарушена 1-я нормальная форма - в одном поле вы храните время работы. Если это не timestamp (что бессмысленно, ведь в этой ситуации интересует именно время начала и окончания), то это нарушение 1НФ.
3. Весьма сомнительно выглядит отдельная таблица для номеров домов.
4. Столь же сомнительно наличие в таблице улиц, ссылки на таблицу номеров домов и отсутствие таковой в таблице адресов.
5. По всей вероятности, было бы неплохо завести таблицу городов.

Comment: Я изменил таблицу с расписанием и таблицу с адресом. Но мне все еще не понятно, как уходить от использования составных первичных ключей в таблицах Кредиты и Депозиты? Спасибо.

Comment: сделайте их несоставными, в чем проблема-то?

Comment: Я, кажется, понял, не имеет смысла делать в таблицах Кредиты и Депозиты поле id_банка ключевым. В ключевых полях следует оставить только id_депозита.

Comment: Конкретно в этих случаях - да, не имеет. Здесь id банка вообще не влияет на уникальность записи. Запись уникально определяется собственным id депозита/кредита.  То же самое касается и всех остальных таблиц, где есть составные ключи, - это бессмысленно и даже вредно

Comment: И все таки, в одном случае составной ключ может помочь. В таблице Расписание каждая запись описывает режим работы для отделения в конкретный день недели, и если принять за ключ id_записи, то может возникнуть ситуация когда для одного отделения в один день недели будет два расписания. Поэтому есть смысл использовать составной ключ id/_отделения + день_недели.

Comment: @nekaneka нет тут никакого смысла использовать составной ключ. Составные ключи - это вообще зло, так скажем. Первичные ключи не должны задавать ограничения на вторичные ключи, это во-первых, а во-вторых, ситуация, когда у вас для одного отделения есть два расписания - это нормальная ситуация. Скажем, если у вас отделение работает с 8 часов утра до 13, потом уходит на обеденный перерыв и далее работает с 14 до 16. Тем самым получится, что вам нужно иметь две записи для одного отделения на один день, и это вполне нормально.
Искренне рекомендую забыть о составных первичных ключах, они не нужны.